# Finding the number of times a column switches back and forth per day in R

Tags: r

I would appreciate help figuring out how to tell if my column in R switches from "Bottom_Half" to "Basking". Here's an example of my data so you can see what I'm referencing.

The reproducible example is giant and I have no idea how to reduce it down. So instead I'll insert a picture of what the data set looks like. I tried dput(head(my_data, 10)) and it was over 260,000 characters. Please help me figure out how else I can show the data set. It's 3744 obs. of 3 variables.

[image]

What I want to do is count the number of times the column "Position" switches from being Bottom_Half to Basking per day. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

JUST ADDED: Here's an example code you can run that's set up the same way (L1 doesn't really matter in this case):

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(rep(as.Date('2017-05-21'), 10), rep(as.Date('2017-05-22'), 10)),
                 Position = sample(c('Bottom_Half','Basking'), 20, T))
df
         date    Position
1  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
2  2017-05-21     Basking
3  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
4  2017-05-21     Basking
5  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
6  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
7  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
8  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
9  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
10 2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
11 2017-05-22     Basking
12 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
13 2017-05-22     Basking
14 2017-05-22     Basking
15 2017-05-22     Basking
16 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
17 2017-05-22     Basking
18 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
19 2017-05-22     Basking
20 2017-05-22     Basking
```

Comment: do `dput(head(my_data[, c('date', 'turtle', 'Position')], 10))`

Comment: @onyambu that still didn't work. instead of only the first 10 rows appearing, they basically all show up so all the individual dates and times are listed (which is a lot)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame(date = c(rep(as.Date('2017-05-21'), 10), rep(as.Date('2017-05-22'), 10)),
                 Position = sample(c('Bottom_Half','Basking'), 20, T))
df
         date    Position
1  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
2  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
3  2017-05-21     Basking
4  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
5  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
6  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
7  2017-05-21     Basking
8  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
9  2017-05-21 Bottom_Half
10 2017-05-21     Basking
11 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
12 2017-05-22     Basking
13 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
14 2017-05-22     Basking
15 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
16 2017-05-22     Basking
17 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
18 2017-05-22     Basking
19 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
20 2017-05-22 Bottom_Half
df %>% group_by(Day = lubridate::day(date)) %>% summarise(c = max(cumsum(Position != 'Bottom_Half')))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    Day     c
  <int> <int>
1    21     3
2    22     4
```

Comment: Should the result be 3 instead of 7? I only see three changes from `Botton_Half` to Basking. or should you also include changes from basking to bottom half?

Comment: @Onyambu, you are right, have made the change.

Comment: @karthik S When I do this, my day 2 value has NA for the c value. I have no idea why since I know the Position value changes at least once. I also forgot to mention that when the turtle goes from Top_Half to Basking I also needed that counted (in the same count as Bottom_Half). Futhermore, I'm getting counts that are in the tens (like 74, and 68) and I know for a fact it doesn't switch that much because I've manually counted a few.